# Get home wallpaper and set it to my activity

Tags: android, desktop-wallpaper

I want to get the home wallpaper set and put it as my background for my activity. Is this possible ?

I searched on the internet with

```
WallpaperInfo v = w.getWallpaperInfo();
String name = v.getServiceName();
```

I have the service name (because the wallpaper is a live service) for example, I have `com.android.wallpaper.grass.GrassWallpaper`...can I use this to start service into my activity?

If so, how?

Answer (score 8):

Try to add this attribute to your  tag in the manifest:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper"

Answer (score 4):

It seems you even haven't tried to do anything... whatever, you can get the wallpaper by doing:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Then, you can use that drawable and set it as the background of your activity.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know whether that's possible. Try to see if the `getWallpaperInfo()` gives you enough information to extract the wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

using `WalpaperManager` requires `storage permition`. so I suggest this amazing way:

if your main theme name is `AppTheme`, some thing like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

then create another theme named `AppTheme.Wallpaper`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Wallpaper" parent="AppTheme">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```

then put that theme in the manifest as your activity attribute:

```
<activity android:name=".YOUR_ACTIVITY"
    
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Wallpaper">

</activity>
```